# How to render images which are stored using multer in express app?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have stored images with multer on express app server. But I am not getting that images to use in my html files.

Code to upload file.

```
var multer = require("multer")

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname+'/public/uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now()+file.originalname)
  }
})
app.post('/add/details', upload.any(), function(req,res){
  var data = req.body;
  data.propic = req.files[0].path;
  res.render('index',{
    "data": data
  });
})
```

In index file I am setting src of img to data.propic but it's not showing image.

Comment: which `render` engine you are using?

Comment: I am using jade engine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
router.use(fileUpload());

sampleFile = req.files.team_image;
file_name = sampleFile.name;
sampleFile.mv('public/storage/'+file_name, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saving the images in `public/images` folder, you can take advantage of `express.static` for serving these newly uploaded files automatically.

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require("multer")

var app = express();

//all static contents inside the given folder will be accessible
//e.g. http://example.com/public/uploads/test.png
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public/uploads'));

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname+'/public/uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now()+file.originalname)
  }
});

app.post('/add/details', upload.any(), function(req,res){
   var data = req.body;
   // path of uploaded file.
   data.propic = '/public/uploads/'+req.files[0].filename;
   res.render('index',{
      "data": data
   });
});
```

Assume that you are using `jade` as view engine, you can embed `img` as following:

```
img(src=data.propic) // it's equivalent to http://example.com/public/uploads/test.png
```

Comment: This worked but needed some twiks. in index.jade file i have to write img(src='/'+data.propic). And to set propic in data object only req.files[0].filename did the trick. Like `data.propic = req.files[0].filename;`

Comment: yeah i did accept but it says reputation must be 15 i am newbie to stackoverflow. sorry.